# XML traversal with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have an xml file with data in it and i am trying to add this data into arrays.

```
 <values>     
  <value date="2015-07-12">37.170</value>
  <value date="2015-07-13">7.190</value>
  <value date="2015-07-12">37.170</value>
  <value date="2015-07-12">3.210</value>
  <value date="2015-07-12">37.20</value>
 <dgauges><d>27.470</d><d-1>27.800</d-1><d-2>27.980</d-2><d-3>28.060</d-3></dgauges>
</values>
```

I already have all the values into an array named data, but when using the same type of loop to get the children of the dgauges I get nothing

```
var data = [];
        var start;
        var end;
        console.log(data);
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $.ajax({
               type:'post',        //just for ECHO
               dataType: "xml", // type of file you are trying to read
               crossDomain:true,
               url: './../CurrentFiles/test.xml', // name of file you want to parse
               success: parse, // name of the function to call upon success
               async:    false,
               error: function(xhr, status, error) { 
                   console.log(error);
                   console.log(status);
               }
           });

           function parse(xmldata) {
               console.log("start");
               $(xmldata).find("value").each(function(){
                   data.push($(this).text());
               });
               var dguages = [];
               $(xmldata).children('dgauges').each(function(){
                   console.log("good");
                   console.log($(this).text() + "\n");
               });

           }
               console.log(data);
               if(data.length == 0){
                  window.location.href = "./test.html";
                 }
        });
```

I am also trying to get the first and last date? How would I go about finding the dates, and adding them to an array. 
Not sure what I am doing wrong to the the dgauges child values.

if i wanted to make a function that would gget a certain xml file by name in jquery how would i do that?

```
            var dguages = [];
            function getXML(location,day){
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type:'post',        //just for ECHO
                    dataType: "xml", // type of file you are trying to read
                    crossDomain:true,
                    url: './../CurrentFiles/'+ location +'.xml', // name of file you want to parse
                    success: function (xmldata){
                        if(dguages[0] == null){
                            $(xmldata).find('dgauges').children().each(function(){
                               dguages.push($(this).text());
                             });console.log(dguages);dguages = dguages;
                        }
                     }, // name of the function to call upon success
                    async:    false,
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) { 
                        console.log(error);
                        console.log(status);
                    }
                });
            });
            console.log(dguages);
            return dguages[day];
        }
      console.log(getXML("AUGA4",1));
```

I am having trouble getting the dguage array to store the data. when I call it out of the method there are no elements in the array. but calling console.log(dguages) ind side the parse function it shows it being full.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are finding all children of type `dgauges` and looping over them instead of finding the children of the `dgauges` tag.

Change this:

`$(xmldata).children('dgauges').each(function(){`

Into:

`$(xmldata).find('dgauges').children().each(function(){`

To access the data parameter in the value tag as you requested, simply look up the data attribute:

```
var dates = [];
$(xmldata).find("value").each(function(){
                   dates[dates.length] = $(this).attr('date');
                   data.push($(this).text());
               });
```

Then you can look for the min/max as requested in the array

Comment: I am not sure if I understand how you found the first and last dates. why would you use dates[dates.length]?

Comment: If i read this right the find tag just finds the attribute but no the children, but combining both of them will find the children.

Comment: @Jay each `value` has its `date` property appended to the `dates` array. You could find the first using simple array techniques such as `dates[0]` to get the first date, and `dates[dates.length-1]` to find the last value

Comment: @Jay, yes the `find` command will find all the elements that match the selector, however, in order to select its children, then you must add the `children` command to then grab anything under what you found

Comment: @Jay, I don't understand your question

Comment: I am having trouble getting the dguage array to store the data. when I call it out of the method there are no elements in the array. but calling console.log(dguages) ind side the parse function it shows it being full.

Comment: @Jay, well, you define `dguages` inside of a function, therefore, it will only be available inside that function. If you want a variable to be global, you need to define it in the global scope first